What are the asymptotic properties of plain kolmogorov complexity?
This is somewhat of a vague question, but here is an example:
If $C$ is plain kolmogorov complexity, and $f$ is a computable injective function, does $C(f(t)) = \Theta(C(t))$ regardless of the encoding of $t$?
I think it must. Here is a rough sketch of a proof but there may be some "gaps". By the axiomatic definition of kolmogorov complexity
$$C(f(t)) \leq C(t) + c_f \qquad (*)$$
for some constant $c_f$. But if $f$ is injective, there is an inverse map $f^{-1}$ on the codomain of $f$ that is computable on the codomain.
I think we have
$$C(f^{-1}(f(t))) \leq C(f(t)) + c_{f^{-1}}$$
Which is the same as
$$C(t) \leq C(f(t)) + c_2 \qquad (**)$$
So by combining $(*)$ and $(**)$ doesn't that imply that $C(f(t)) = \Theta(C(t))$?
Tl;dr
Here are specific questions I want answered

Is the above argument correct? i.e. does $C(f(t)) = \Theta(C(t))$ for injective $f$?
Is there a nice function $f$ such that $C(t) = \Theta(f(t))$?
When is it the case that  $C(f(t)) \sim C(t)$?

